# Rally rallyaddnew with Portfolio Items

Tags: rally

I have been trying to use a rallyaddnew to add Features and Rollups, which will then be rendered in a grid/cardboard.  I got it to work and display, but I cannot customize the text to say create a new "Feature" or "Rollup", rather it says create a new "PortfolioItem/Feature" and "PortfolioItem/Rollup"

```
{
    xtype: 'rallyaddnew',
    recordTypes: ['PortfolioItem/Feature', 'PortfolioItem/Rollup'], 
    listeners: {
    recordAdd: function() {
        //
    },
    beforeRecordAdd: function() {
        //
    }
}
```

I couldn't find anything in the SDK on how to customize this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a defect.  It should be using the display name of the type instead of its type path.  I'll file a defect for this.  FYI there is also an existing defect around PI types and adding with details that has been fixed but has not been released in an SDK version yet.

Comment: Thanks. I also want to eventually be able to customize it to say whatever I want, not just have it say "Feature" and "Rollup" - did you include that?

Comment: I ended up just setting hiding that element: `#addMore > div.x-container > div.x-box-inner > div > table.x-field > tbody > tr > td.x-form-item-body > table > tbody > tr > td {
    display: none;
}` and then I would set the appropriate one based on a different combobox.  Hope this helps anyone else with a similar issue while we wait for a fix!